# Specifying the colours for two scatter plots in the same graph for

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Below we see a graph with two plots. I would like to have the series S1 with the same colour in each of the plots.
[image]

However, it seems that the colours are being attributed by alphabetic order.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
plot1<-ggplot(data=dfp)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Save,y=Obsdata,colour="S1"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Save,y=BiasCorrected,colour="S2"))+
  xlab("X")+ylab("Y")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

plot2<-ggplot(data=dfp)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Save,y=SModel, colour="R3"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=Save,y=Obsdata,colour="S1"))+
  xlab("X")+ylab("Y")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please hover over the R tag - it asks for a minimal reproducible example. [Here's a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). In your example, `dfp` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a manual color palette like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=runif(90), y=runif(90), col=gl(3,30,labels=LETTERS[1:3]), fac=gl(2,45))
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df[df$fac==1,], aes(x,y,color=col)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(df[df$fac==2,], aes(x,y,color=col)) + geom_point()
pal <- list(scale_color_manual(values = c("A"="red", "B"="blue", "C"="darkgreen")))
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1 + pal, p2 + pal, ncol = 2)
```

Also note the facetted option `ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=col)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~fac)`.